# Update a Git repository from another repository

Tags: git

I have been working on a custom MVC framework project in PHP so that I can build websites on top of it and I have the project in a repository on BitBucket.org.

Using this framework I would like to create multiple seperate websites which will each have their own repositories.

Is it possible, and if so how would I go about it, to copy the main framework to a folder locally, build a new website, and then in the future if I update the main framework I can then go ahead and update all my sites.

For example, say I downloaded CakePHP 2.1 and had built three different sites in three different directories. Then they updated their framework to 2.2, and I wanted to just merge those updates into each website project.

I have a vague understanding of submodules but I don't think this is really what I'm looking for.

Comment: You should publish your framework as a package, and then use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) to manage the dependency for the individual websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a base project at `github:user/base`, and custom site projects at `github:user/site1` and `github:user/site2`, that were each derived from the base project. that is, site1 and site2 were originally cloned from base, and then you worked on them, they have their unique commits, so does base, so at the this point all these repositories have diverged from each other.

Even though the repositories have diverged, they share a common history. You can get the changes from the base project into the custom site projects with `git merge`.

I started doing this myself recently. In the working tree of `site1` and `site2`, I define two remotes:

1. `origin`: points to `github:user/site1` in site1, `github:user/site2` in site2
2. `upstream`: points to `github:user/base` in both site1 and site2

When I want to bring in the changes from the base, I use these commands:

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git push
```

However, conflicts are very common in the `merge` step, but that's probably because my project is very young and I make quite profound changes in the base. It's good if you're comfortable resolving conflicts.

Comment: Thank you for this response. It works just as I needed. I have tried to build my base in a way that should never be edited by a site that uses it. The only conflict I now get is the readme.md file.

Answer (score 0):

The last step (update the various sites based on changes to the master) needs a little work outside of Git. Here's how I'd set things up:

The main framework repository is a Git repository. It's got some stub locations for where the sites will put there stuff:

```
main/
  framework/
    js/
      bla.js
      foo.js
    php/
      bar.php
    css/
      start.css
  site/
```

Now clone this repository for your sites and (this is the important bit) *only add things to the "site" sub-directory*.

In the main framework repository, only modify things under the "framework" sub-directory.

If you keep that partitioning, you'll be able to simply "git pull" in the site repositories, and Git will fast-forward merge the changes from "main" into your site repo.

The tangle will come if you ever need to make a change to the framework, but only have it apply to one site.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It was a good idea but my folder structure is more intertwined. I am using a similar structure to cake and the site files are placed within the framework, but the core of the framework isn't to be edited.